# Is the image of an algebraic element by a non zero morphism algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/k_0$ and $L/k_1$ be two field extensions and $\sigma:K\to L$ be a non zero morphism such that $\sigma(k_0)\subset k_1$. Consider an element $\alpha\in K$ algebraic over $k_0$. Is $\sigma(\alpha)$ algebraic over $k_1$?

My try: Consider an algebraic relation for $\alpha$: there exsit $a_i\in k_0$ ($0\le i\le n$) not all zero such that
$$\sum_{i=0}^na_i\alpha^i=0.$$
One has
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sigma(a_i)\sigma(\alpha)^i=0.$$
But maybe all the $\sigma(a_i)$ are zero. Can one assert that one of the $a_i$'s is non zero at least?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Pick a polynomial $f\in k_0[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. What can you say about $\sigma(f(\alpha))$? Can you find $g\in k_1[x]$ such that $\sigma(f(\alpha))=g(\sigma(\alpha))$?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But have a look at my edit. My problem is that I am not sure that the image of the polynomial is not zero.

Comment: Ring morphisms between fields are injective. Hence, $\sigma(a_i)=0$ iff $a_i=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I never thought about that. It was my missing part. Proof of this fact is very easy in fact.

Comment: You can prove this by noting that the kernel of $\sigma$ is an ideal of $K$. Now recall what the ideals of a fields are (there are only two) and then use that $ker(\sigma)\neq K$ as $\sigma$ is not the zero morphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that ring homomorphisms between fields are injective if the homomorphism is not the zero homomorphism. For this we note that the kernel of our ring homomorphism $\sigma$ is an ideal of $K$. As $K$ is a field, this means that $ker(\sigma)=\{0\}$ or $ker(\sigma)=K$. The second option is ruled out by the assumption that $\sigma$ is not the zero homomorphism and thus $ker(\sigma)$ is trivial, hence $\sigma$ injective.

Thus, we get $\sigma(a_i)=0$ iff $a_i=0$ and we are in business (not all $a_i$ vanish and therefore also not all $\sigma(a_i)$ vanish).